# Injectivity and surjectivity of $\prod_{i=1}^m W_i \to \sum_{i=1}^m W_i$ given by $(w_i)_i \mapsto \sum_i w_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

> Suppose $W_1,W_2,\dotsc,W_m$ are subspaces of $V$. Define a map
>   $$
>          T
>   \colon W_1 \times W_2 \times \dotsb \times W_m
>   \to    W_1 + W_2 + \dotsb + W_m
> $$
>   by
>   $$
>   T(w_1,w_2,...,w_m) = w_1 + w_2 + \dotsb + w_m.
> $$
>
> a)
>   Show that $T$ is surjective.
>
> b)
>   Show that $T$ is injective if and only if $W_1 + W_2 + \dotsb + W_m$ is a direct sum.

I know that if $\dim( \operatorname{im}(T)) = \dim(W_1 \times W_2 \times \dotsb \times W_m)$, then $T$ is surjective and if $\dim(\ker(T))=0$, then $T$ is injective. I am not sure how to proceed with the proof.

Comment: Tip. $\times$ is available as \times [wrapped by dollar symbols].

Comment: Hint: just use definition. Also $\mathcal T$ is invective iff $\dim(\mathrm {Ker}(\mathcal T)) = 0$, not $\mathrm {Im}(\mathcal T)$.

Comment: BTW, $\mathcal T \colon W_1 \times \cdots \times W_m \to  W_1 + W_2 + \cdots + W_m$ might not be linear at all, so there is actually no reason to talk about dimensions of image and kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Suppose $r \in W_1 + W_2 + \ldots + W_m$, then $\exists w_i \in W_i, i \in \{ 1, \ldots, m\}$ such that $r=w_1 + \ldots + w_m$. Hence it is surjective.
- Suppose it is injective, then for every vector in $W_1+\ldots +W_m$, there is exactly one way to decompose the vector. In particular, there is exactly one way to decompose the zero vector, hence it is a direct sum.
- Suppose it is a direct sum, then there is exactly one way to decompose the zero vector. I will leave this as an exercise, try to show that it is an injection.